# How to insert multiple files into database, using Java Servlet 3.1

Tags: java, mysql, database

once again I need your help. I am trying to insert multiple files into DB table. I managed to insert 1 file - 1 row in the DB table, however I do not know how to do it for multiple files - multiple rows, in one request.

This is the part of my Servlet where I get the file from the html input:

```
InputStream otherFileInputStream = null;            
Part otherFilesPart = request.getPart("other_files");

if (otherFilesPart != null && otherFilesPart.getSize() != 0) {
    otherFileInputStream = otherFilesPart.getInputStream();                
}
```

And this is the method that I use for inserting the file into the database:

```
private int addOtherFiles(long personId, int userId) throws SQLException {
    int res = 0;
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
    String sql = "insert into person_other_files(person_fk, other_files, user_fk) values (?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    
    if (otherFileInputStream != null) {
        ps.setLong(1, personId);        
        ps.setBlob(2, otherFileInputStream);
        ps.setInt(3, userId);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    }        
    return res;
}
```

When a user uploads 2 or 3 files, there should be 2-3 rows with the files uploaded? Bear in mind, that I do can not use Apache Commons for uploading files. The main idea is: In my website I have 2 different input type file **multiple** fields, which are corresponding to 2 different DB tables.

Comment: If you have a defined amount of file, like 2 files max, yes add 2 column.
Else, maybe you have just use something like a JSON which contains a list of all files

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, a user uploads files from his computer to your website and by 2-3 rows you mean a row per file/filepath, right? In any case you probably need to use a `for` loop to go through every file uploaded by the user.

Comment: @SikorskyS60 yes, you understood right. But in my request, I am getting the file name -> "other_files" , because I have a lot of other file fields which I want to submit in different tables. And I can't use get.Parts() because it is only used for 1 multiple type file field. I don't know how to implement your comment for my solution.

Comment: Please give an example of what is in one of your "files".  (Usually, that refers to a CSV file with lots of rows being loaded into one table.)

Comment: @RickJames there is an html form with two input type "file" multiple fields. Every user can upload whatever type of file/files they want to each one of them. These files, for example: 2 pds should be uploaded in SQL table as two rows 1 row: first pdf, 2 row: second pdf.

Comment: If the html form allows the user to upload multiple files, use separate _rows_, not _columns_.  If the app requires exactly 2 files to be uploaded, then two _columns_ is OK.

Comment: Do you intend to put a file in a column of the table?  Or put a file on disk, then put a URL in the table?  (I prefer the latter.)

Comment: @RickJames This is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dkrygeqx/  You can see that there are 2 multiple type files. File1 should go in a table called table_file_1. File2 should go in a table called table_file_2. The thing is that the user can upload multiple files for File1 which will be rows in table_file_1. The same goes to table_file_2 as well.

Comment: `HttpServletRequest` has `getParts` which should contain all the parts (files) of a `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Can you please add bare minimum code to directly copy and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop inside your transaction essentially like this:

```
 con.setAutoCommit(false); // enable transaction, turning off the auto- 
                           // commit

 String sql = "INSERT INTO person_other_files(person_fk, other_files, user_fk) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

 for (String file : files) // "files" is your list of files
 {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    Path filePath = Paths.get(file);
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);

    if (bytes != null)
    {
        ps.setLong(1, personId);
        ps.setBlob(2, bytes);
        ps.setInt(3, userId);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    }
  }

  con.commit(); // commit transaction at the end
```

Don't forget exception handling (ommitted for clarity)!

Regards